# Indesign page size

Tags: adobe-indesign

Using InDesign, I formatted one of my books as an 8x10, and although I placed the headers slightly above the safe zone and far from the bleed and trim lines, once printed by Lightning Source, the header was way too close to the final trim. I also noticed that the final trim size for my ARC was not exactly 8x10 but a tad smaller.

My question is... should I set my page size to 8.25 x 10.25 without adding a visual bleed? If so, what would be the correct settings?

Comment: LightningSource has specific specifications for their print on demand items. You need to follow those exactly.

Comment: I did. I was in constant communication with IngramSpark/Lightning Source via phone, during the entire process.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the page size for the size it will be trimmed out and then add bleeds. The trim line is where it is cut. The bleed line is completely off the page to cover any adjustments when the page is trimmed.

It sounds like maybe you put the information too close to the trim line (edge of document).

[image: 8.5 x 11 with bleeds]

Comment: That is not what happened. I set it for my desired trim size, and set the bleed and slug, as you show in your image. I had no text too close to the trim line. But thanks for your input.

Comment: The answer to your question is no, you should not set your page size to include your bleeds. Maybe your print vendor has particular specs that should be followed.